# How to write Jasmine unit testing code of a http call from a service , which fetches the data from another service in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have tried to write unit testing of a httpmock one of a service which uses a method (function) to get http get call, but failed to write.

**saveservice.service.ts -- file**

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
const envURL = sessionStorage.getItem('apiBaseURL');
 httpGet<T>(url) {
    const URL = envURL + url;
    return this.http.get<T>(URL, httpOptions);
  }
```

this is how workservice and save service are connected.Now I want to write unit test case for work.component.ts file,but Iam unable to write the httpmock calls there .

For info, apiUrl is present in a different file named env.ts file-- env.ts

**env.ts -- file**

```
export const apivalue= {

    apiBaseUrl:"https://example.co/",
  };
```

**work.service.ts**

```
import {SaveserviceService } from '../../.././saveservice.service';

getworklist(employeeID){

    return this.saveservice.httpGet('work/v1/works?employeeid=' + employeeID);
  }
```

this is how workservice and save service are connected.Now I want to write unit test case of for work.component.ts file,but Iam unable to write the httpmock calls there .

**work.component.ts**

```
ngOnit(){
this.employeeID:this.id;
   this.workservice.getworkList(this.employeeID).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.workList = data;
       console.log(" ggghfghfgh", this.worklist);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);}
```

Above one is work.component.ts file for which i should write unit test cases.Please help me to complete it.

**work.component.spec.ts**

```
 let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
 let injector: Injector;
  let workservice: WorksService;
let saveservice123: SaveService;

 providers: [
        Injector,
        HttpClient,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        saveService,
        worksService
      ],

  httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    workservice = TestBed.get(WorksService);
    saveservice123 = TestBed.get(SaveService)

  fit('getting work detsails indivually', async(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(worksComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    workservice.getworklist(123).subscribe(() =>{});

    const request = httpMock.expectOne("work/v1/works?employeeid=")
    // expect(request.request.method).toBe('httpGet');
    // request.flush(xxxxx);
```

its throwing below  error

```
Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: work/v1/works?employeeid=", found none.
```

Please help , how to know to write unit test cases for this type..
I also tried to spy also,

```
const mockdata = { id:1, title: "Hello world",  paste: "console.log('Hello world');"}
     const spyOnAdd = spyOn(service, "getworkList").and.returnValue(mockdata);
```

Comment: You could test those two services *separately*. You'll have to think about where the base URL comes from for the save service, but you can replace it with a test double when testing the work service. Spying on the method you're testing doesn't make sense. See https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: thanks for your reply @jonrsharpe, Firstly-- i just tried the spy method apart from the other, but not wrote entirely.Secondly,as u said i will try writing in different test cases,but i wanna know how would it help in fetching the httpmock url thing in workservice spec file ?

Comment: I have metioned there about the apiUrl thing, it is written in a different env. ts file.   Could you please help me understand "you can replace it with a test double when testing the work service" , how can we do this

Comment: @jonrsharpe  could you please help me  to write it

Comment: i have tried many ways, could anyone help me to sort it out.